# Using import wizard to copy csv file that has two columns of numeric data result gives all null values in postgre

Tags: postgresql, import, null

I have a two column csv file that has only numeric data.  I create a table in Postgre with the columns as numeric.  I successfully use the import wizard, but it gives all my values in the postgre table as null.  Not sure why.

Comment: Would you mind showing a few lines of the data that you're importing? Also, what tool are you using to import the data?

Comment: here are the steps I used.  I create a database in pgAdmin4.  I create a table called users and create 2 columns: UserID and OrgID and select numeric for data type for each column.  I then  use the import/export feature for Table to import with header a csv file.  here are the first few lines of the file. (added i n separate comment).  I get the message successful import, but the values are displayed as [Null].  Not sure why that is happening.  I open the CSV in Excel, and the data is numeric.

Comment: UserID OrgID
20964 83
53492 114
19680 120
31499 122